# Dealing with newline when parsing for a regex match in a file

Tags: regex, perl

i've got a file that is formatted with newlines, and i need to count the matches for a regex. The problem is that reading and testing the file every line of it, i lose all the matches that are in between the lines

```
while ($row = <$fh>) {
  if ( $row =~ regexp ) {
     #do stuff
```

Example file

match string: rogerbravo

file:

```
alphalphaspamrogerbravo --> match ok.
alphaalphaspamspamroger --> occurrence lost
bravospamspamspamspamro --> lost
gerbravospamsspamspamsp
```

I wonder if there is an elegant solution to this, still reading one line at a time, because the file is a 5GB text file.

Thanks

EDIT:
The regexp is of this form:  /(.+?)([ATG][TC]A.[TCG][AG]AT[CT][TAG])/gi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

Here's a version that searches lines in pairs. At the end of each pass it deletes up to the last occurrence of the pattern, if one was found, or up to the end of the first of the two lines if not, and then appends an additional line from the file. This way the data buffer can never contain more than two lines of data

There is still one small proviso that this method will miss occurrences of the pattern that are split across *three* lines, like

```
rog
erb
ravo
```

but I assume that this is impossible

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $count = 0;
my $pattern = 'rogerbravo';

chomp(my $data = <DATA>);

while ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    my $split = length $data;
    $data .= $_;
    printf "Data buffer %d characters\n", length $data;

    while ( $data =~ /$pattern/g ) {
        ++$count;
        $split = $+[0];
    }

    $data = substr $data, $split;
}


printf qq{%d occurrences of "%s"\n}, $count, $pattern;

__DATA__
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
alphalphaspamrogerbravo
alphaalphaspamspamroger
bravospamspamspamspamro
gerbravospamsspamspamsp
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
```

#### output

```
Data buffer 46 characters
Data buffer 46 characters
Data buffer 46 characters
Data buffer 23 characters
Data buffer 46 characters
Data buffer 41 characters
Data buffer 38 characters
Data buffer 46 characters
Data buffer 46 characters
3 occurrences of "rogerbravo"
```

#### Original solution

If you keep a data buffer and append lines to it one at a time, and then remove the characters up to each occurrence of the pattern, then your memory usage will be kept small

This will work fine as long as there are sufficient occurrences of the pattern to keep the the buffer small

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $count = 0;
my $data = '';
my $pattern = 'rogerbravo';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    $data .= $_;
    ++$count while $data =~ s/.*?$pattern//g;
}


say qq{$count occurrences of "$pattern"};


__DATA__
alphalphaspamrogerbravo
alphaalphaspamspamroger
bravospamspamspamspamro
gerbravospamsspamspamsp
```

#### output

```
3 occurrences of "rogerbravo"
```

Comment: Hmm, so use the 'replace' pattern to delete up to the last full match from the buffer?. That's elegant.

Comment: @Sobrique: My only reservation is that it achieves nothing if the 5GB file has one occurrence of the pattern right at the end. Something rather more clever involving counting within pairs of lines at a time is needed to get around that

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. By the way don't you think that would be easier to analyze the file taking chinks of it in a string wihout newline?

Comment: @BlueStarry: I'm not sure I understand. That's pretty much what my code does -- the chunks are lines of the file and I remove newlines with `chomp` after reading each one

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer I can think of - based on what you've given so far - why not set your record separator to `rogerbravo`.

e.g.

```
local $/ = 'rogerbravo';
```

Because then your while loop will fire each time it hits it, and `$.` will be the number of occurences. Unfortunately a limitation of doing this is that `$/` doesn't support regular expressions - `rogerbravo` and `roger\nbravo` are not the same. So it may well not work, because of the problem of linefeeds embedded - you effectively have a bunch of different patterns you're trying to match.

Otherwise you might have to do a 'rolling chunk' based approach splicing together lines:

```
 my $prev_line = ''; 
 my $prev_count = 0; 
 while ( my $line = <$input_fh> ) { 
     chomp ( $line ); 
     my $count = $prev_line.$line =~ m/rogerbravo/g; 
     $total += $count - $prev_count; 
     $prev_count = $line =~ m/rogerbravo/g; #just instances in _this_ line
     #to exclude from next iteration. 
     $prev_line = $line; 
 }
```

Something like that anyway. (Sorry, haven't really tested it, I don't really have enough sample data - might require some verification to ensure it isn't doublecounting)

You can do similar with setting read-by-bytes by setting `$/` to a reference to a numeric value:

```
local $/ = \2048;
```

If your pattern is small enough, you only have to look at the boundary area to see if the last few bytes contains the start of your pattern.

E.g.

```
 local $/ = \2048; 
 my $trailing = ''; 
 while ( my $chunk = <$input_fh> ) {
     $chunk =~ s/\n//g; 
     my $count_in_this_chunk = $chunk =~ m/rogerbravo/g; 
     ( $trailing ) = $chunk =~ m/(\w{9})$/; # 9 because 'rogerbravo' is 10
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The problem is that my "rogerbravo" in the example is a regexp of this form: /(.+?)([ATG][TC]A.[TCG][AG]AT[CT][TAG])/gi

Comment: That's probably worth adding to the question. First principle won't apply (but didn't anyway). But the later two probably will. (In both cases you're wrapping part of your pattern into the next chunk)

Comment: @BlueStarry: You should remove the `.+?` from your pattern. It's unnecessary and makes the code slower and less clear